# Android display address of specific one BLE devices

Tags: android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an application to coommunicate against a BLE device, currently I want to know  how to display address of specific one ble device.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bad in so many ways, but I'll still provide an answer: `BluetoothDevice#getAddress()`.